# i have an issue with the linked list iam trying to add but the debuger says that cant acces memory of temp

Tags: c, linked-list, insert, singly-linked-list

I am trying to insert data to the end of the list, but it's not working: an exception occurs at runtime.

```
struct gradeNode *newNode = (struct gradeNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct gradeNode));
assert(newNode != NULL);

strcpy(newNode->courseName, courseName); // copying the course name
newNode->next = NULL;

struct gradeNode *temp = students[i].gradelist->head; // a temp

// here is the problem: the debugger says ecxeption, can't access memory 
while (temp->next != NULL) 
{
    temp = temp->next; // I can't get to here
    temp->next = newNode;
}
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: Is `students[i].gradelist->head` properly initialized? When do this happen? Is `temp` a null or otherwise invalid pointer? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. And please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @loay  It seems that temp is equal to NULL.

Comment: On an unrelated note, `assert` is not a function but a *macro*. A macro that doesn't do anything in "release" builds. Don't use it for proper error checking and validation.

Comment: @loay And ignore the reference about castings. There is an answer of a very weak programmer. .

Comment: How did you think this mess was well written enough to post?

Comment: Please post the code for how you initialize `students[i].gradelist->head`

Answer (score 0):

In this code snippet

```
    struct gradeNode *temp = students[i].gradelist->head;//a temp
    while (temp->next != NULL)//
```

either the data member `head` is not properly initialized or is equal to NULL. In the both cases the expression `temp->next` results in undefined behavior.

And this loop (after you edited your code)

```
while (temp->next != NULL) 
{
    temp = temp->next; // I can't get to here
    temp->next = newNode;
}
```

does not make sense. It seems you mean

```
while (temp->next != NULL) 
{
    temp = temp->next; // I can't get to here
}
temp->next = newNode;
```

In any case the used approach is wrong.

Instead try the following

```
    struct gradeNode **temp = &students[i].gradelist->head;//a temp
    while ( *temp ) temp = &( *temp )->next;

    *temp = newNode;
```

Take into account that it is logically inconsistent to have a one-sided singly-linked list and to try to append data to the end of the list. If you want to append data to a singly-linked list to its end then the list should be defined as a two-sided linked list.

Comment: iam sorry iam new to c so my code is a bit missy my code works on codeblocks but it dosn`t work on visualstudio the problem is here  ` struct gradeNode *temp = students[i].gradelist->head;
   while (temp->next != NULL)
   {`    **
struct Stud {
 int id;
 float gradeAverage;
 float incomeAverage;
 struct gradeList *gradelist;
 struct incomeList *incomelist;
};

typedef struct Stud Students;

struct gradeNode {
 char courseName[20];
 int grade;
 struct gradeNode *next;
 struct gradeNode *prev;
};**

Comment: @loay I showed in my answer how the function should be implemented.